# Almost similar, but still different algorithm names. What is the difference?

Tags: encryption, tls

I was sent from Stack Overflow to here ([original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957390/almost-similar-but-still-different-algorithm-names-what-is-the-difference)). I'm quite new to cryptographic programming. I want to generate TLS certificates on application boot up time. It is a Spring Boot application, therefore Java and that means I'm using [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/). Right now I have to decide, what the default algorithm would be. I browsed through all given algorithms from Bouncy Castle & now I have a stupid question:

What is the difference between `SHA WITH EC-DSA` and `SHA WITH PLAIN EC-DSA`?

[image]

Comment: PLAIN-ECDSA seems to correspond to section 5.2.1 [here](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/Publications/TechGuidelines/TR03111/BSI-TR-03111_V-2-1_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2) from the BSI (the Federal Office for Information Security in Germany). You can see the BouncyCastle commit [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/commit/d910e131beae185d4b23ca72daf62c6eb5bf3cc4).

Comment: @kodlu It seems to be a typo of Stack Overflow. Anyway, the question has been more fully answered on there now in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957390/almost-similar-but-still-different-algorithm-names-what-is-the-difference).

Comment: Fixed it, sorry was very late...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per that [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/218134), `PLAIN-ECDSA` is specified in section [5.2.1.1](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/Publications/TechGuidelines/TR03111/BSI-TR-03111_V-2-1_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2#subsubsection.5.2.1.1) of BSI TR-03111. It's a variant of [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) with the same functionality and math, but using a different encoding of the signature. The two are thus incompatible unless the verification algorithm purposely accepts both formats (which would be safe, but I guess is uncommon).

The main functional difference is that the X9.62 format has a variable size signature, when `PLAIN-ECDSA` has a constant-size signature.
That's because in the [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) encoding of the signature, the former encodes the $r$ and $s$ components of the signature as two ASN.1 INTEGER, when the later uses the concatenation of the fixed-size representation of $r$ and $s$ as big-endian bytestrings. If and when ASN.1-encoded, the signature is one ASN.1 BIT STRING. OIDs also differ.

For curves with $n$ just below a power of 256 (as many are), the size in X9.62 format is maximal for ≈25.0% of the signatures, one less for ≈49.8%, two less for ≈25.0%, three less for ≈0.195%, four less for ≈0.00114% (going on): the X9.62 format complicates parsing of a signature with an ad-hoc ASN.1 parser, and black-box testing of that.

Thanks to dave_thompson_085 for pointing that my initial answer was dead wrong.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. The OIDs in that BC commit are { id-ecc 4 1 ... } which correspond to TR-03111 section 5.2.1.1 ECDSA not { id-ecc 4 2 ... } in 5.2.1.2 ECGDSA. Moreover you can see in the code that they use the same `ECDSASigner()` as for '{hash}withECDSA' algorithms, and only the encoder differs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : you are right, thanks!  I hopefully fixed the answer.